# Flutter does not save the last build of the project

Tags: android-studio, flutter, ide, builder

When I disconnect the mobile phone from the IDE, it does not save the last compilation of the project, only the last one. Has anyone had this problem using the flutter?

I'm using flutter along with android-studio.

This happens in all my flutter projects.

Comment: It saves the code from the last time you ran `flutter run`. After that hot reload and hot restart changes do not appear when you run it in your device directly. It is meant to be that way.